# Why array not working with function call?

Tags: arrays, c, function

My array not taking inputs (Ex- 5.21).I am trying to take a float input for each of my array elements but this isn't doing this. and Also this function is not working with the array. please help

```
float maxJump (double jumpRecord[], int attempts)
{
    float max = jumpRecord[0];
    for(int i=0; i<attempts; ++i)
    {

        if(jumpRecord[i]>max)
            max = jumpRecord[i];
    }

    printf("Longest Jump = %.2f meter\n",max);
}

int main()
{
    double jumpRecord[5];

    printf("Jumping information (in meter): \n");
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        printf("Attempt %d. = ",i+1);
        scanf("%.2f",&jumpRecord[i]);
    }

    maxJump(jumpRecord,5);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Also this function is not working with the array." This is not a useful description. What is not working? What do you expect, what do you get, what input do you provide? Same for "but this isn't doing this" What is it doing instead? How do you know, you do not care about return value of `scanf` and hence cannot know if it did as expected. You should always check return values of all input/output functions

Answer (score 3):

When used with `scanf()`, `%.2f` (`%f`) format specifier is for reading `float` values.

The elements of `jumpRecord` are `double`, so you should use `%lf` (`%.2lf`) format specifier instead.

Note that `%f` should be used for *printing* `double` via `printf()`. `%lf` is allowed in C99 or later, but `%f` is more portable.